# SDK de mercadopago para Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mercadopago

Buenas tardes....esta disponible el sdk de ios compatible con swift 4? de no estar, tienen idea de cuando estará disponible?? Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Martin, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, saludos!